Remove recursive mutex in Publish/Subscribe implementation
I understand that use of recursive_mutex is considered a code smell, and that generally there is an equivalent implementation using non-recursive mutexes.
How can I remove the recursive_mutex in this threaded Publish/Subscribe implementation?
The PubSub class publishes Container objects to subscribed Observers based on a ContainerProperty which I have simplified to just an int.
The problem I run into is allowing Observers to unsubscribe in the Update() callback.
The UpdateObserver struct and associated functions were added to avoid the possibility of observers being subscribed/unsubscribed during iteration of the observers. But it is still necessary to immediately invalidate an observer on Unsubscribe(), which then requires a lock on the valid property (ObserverList.second) to avoid the case where an observer is destroyed between checking validity and calling Update().
After reading this question I've tried an approach using weak_ptr<Observer> instead of Observer* which removes the requirement to invalidate on Unsubscribe() (since we can just lock() to check if the object still exists before using it). This seems to work, but is quite a significant refactor and runs into other problems. Primarily most of my Observers would subscribe in their constructor, which doesn't play nicely with enable_shared_from_this(). But that is perhaps a separate question.
I would like to find a way to resolve the recursive_mutex directly with as little change to the interface as possible.
observer.h
#ifndef _OBSERVER_H_INCLUDED_
#define _OBSERVER_H_INCLUDED_

#include <vector>

class PubSub;

typedef int ContainerProperty;

struct Container
{
    std::vector<double> data;
    ContainerProperty property;
};

class Observer
{
public:
    Observer(PubSub& p)
        : m_pubSub(p)
    {}
    virtual ~Observer();

    virtual void Update(const Container&) = 0;

protected:
    PubSub& m_pubSub;
};

#endif

observer.cpp
#include "observer.h"
#include "pubsub.h"

Observer::~Observer()
{
    m_pubSub.Unsubscribe(*this);
}

pubsub.h
#ifndef _PUBSUB_H_INCLUDED_
#define _PUBSUB_H_INCLUDED_

#include <condition_variable>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>

#include "observer.h"

//------------------------------------------
//
//------------------------------------------
class PubSubInterface
{
public:
    virtual ~PubSubInterface() = default;

    virtual void Publish(Container&& c) = 0;
    virtual void Subscribe(ContainerProperty p, Observer& o) = 0;
    virtual void Unsubscribe(Observer& o) = 0;
};

//------------------------------------------
//
//------------------------------------------
class PubSub : public PubSubInterface
{
    std::condition_variable m_condition;
    std::queue<Container> m_queue;
    std::mutex m_queueMutex;

    std::thread m_thread;
    bool m_running;

public:
    PubSub()
        : m_running(false)
    {}

    ~PubSub()
    {
        StopThread();

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_queueMutex);

        std::queue<Container>().swap(m_queue);
    }

    bool StartThread()
    {
        if (!m_running)
        {
            m_running = true;

            m_thread = std::thread([=] { PubSubThread(); });
            if (!m_thread.joinable())
            {
                perror("Unable to start PubSub thread");
                m_running = false;
            }
        }

        return m_running;
    }

    void StopThread()
    {
        if (m_running)
        {
            m_running = false;

            // Wake the thread to allow it to join
            Publish(Container());

            if (m_thread.joinable())
            {
                m_thread.join();
            }
        }
    }

    void Publish(Container&& c) override
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_queueMutex);

            m_queue.push(std::move(c));
        }

        m_condition.notify_all();
    }

    void Subscribe(ContainerProperty p, Observer& o) override
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_subscriptionMutex);

        m_observerUpdates.push_back(UpdateObserver(p, o));
    }

    void Unsubscribe(Observer& o) override
    {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_subscriptionMutex);

            m_observerUpdates.push_back(UpdateObserver(o));
        }

        // Invalidate observer immediately
        // Lock prevents an observer being invalidated while iterating in PubSub thread
        std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(m_observerMutex);

        for (auto& property : m_observers)
        {
            for (auto& itr : property.second)
            {
                if (itr.first == &o) itr.second = false;
            }
        }
    }

    void WaitQueueEmpty()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_queueMutex);

        m_condition.wait(lock, [&]() { return m_queue.empty(); });
    }

private:
    Container& front()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_queueMutex);

        m_condition.wait(lock, [&]() { return !m_queue.empty(); });

        return m_queue.front();
    }

    void PubSubThread()
    {
        while (m_running)
        {
            Container& c = front();

            {
                std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(m_observerMutex);

                UpdateObservers();

                const auto& it = m_observers.find(c.property);
                if (it != m_observers.cend())
                {
                    for (const auto& observer : it->second)
                    {
                        if (observer.second)
                        {
                            // recursive_mutex prevents observer being invalidated
                            // after checking validity and avoids deadlock
                            // if Update() in turn calls Unsubscribe()
                            observer.first->Update(c);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_queueMutex);

                m_queue.pop();
            }

            if (m_queue.empty()) m_condition.notify_all();
        }
    }

    void _subscribe(ContainerProperty p, Observer* o)
    {
        m_observers[p][o] = true;
    }

    void _unsubscribe(Observer* o)
    {
        for (auto& observers : m_observers)
        {
            for (auto it = observers.second.begin(); it != observers.second.end();)
            {
                if (!it->second && it->first == o) it = observers.second.erase(it);
                else ++it;
            }
        }
    }

    void UpdateObservers()
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_subscriptionMutex);

        for (const auto& update : m_observerUpdates)
        {
            if (update.m_remove)
            {
                _unsubscribe(update.m_observer);
            }
            else
            {
                _subscribe(update.m_property, update.m_observer);
            }
        }

        m_observerUpdates.clear();
    }

    typedef std::map<Observer*, bool> ObserverMap;
    std::map<ContainerProperty, ObserverMap> m_observers;

    std::recursive_mutex m_observerMutex; // Locks access to the ObserverMap

    struct UpdateObserver
    {
        UpdateObserver(ContainerProperty p, Observer& o)
            : m_property(p), m_observer(&o), m_remove(false) {}

        UpdateObserver(Observer& o)
            : m_property(0), m_observer(&o), m_remove(true) {}

        ContainerProperty m_property;
        Observer* m_observer;
        bool m_remove = false;
    };
    std::list<UpdateObserver> m_observerUpdates;

    std::mutex m_subscriptionMutex; // Locks access to the UpdateObserver list
};

#endif // _PUBSUB_H_INCLUDED_

main.cpp
#include "pubsub.h"

#include <iostream>

class ConcreteObserver : public Observer
{
public:
    ConcreteObserver(PubSub& p)
        : Observer(p)
    {}

private:
    void Update(const Container& c) override
    {
        // Do something with the container 
        // Perhaps unsubscribe or subscribe to other properties
        std::cout << "Handled Container";
    }
};

int main()
{
    PubSub impl;
    impl.StartThread();

    ConcreteObserver o(impl);
    impl.Subscribe(3, o);

    Container c { {1.0, 1.5, 1.2}, 3 };
    impl.Publish(std::move(c));

    // Added for convenience
    // In general I don't care if something is left in the queue at destruction
    impl.WaitQueueEmpty();
}

Compile with g++ main.cpp observer.cpp -lpthread

This code doesn't compile, there are typos and types mismatch. Small usage example is missing, would be good to provide a few lines of int main(). Not everything from PubSub seems to be needed, so you can probably minimize your example to focus on the mutex problem. E.g. Publish(Container&& c) is only used once in the hacky way to implicitly call m_condition.notify_all();

As long as you don't need to "unsubscribe" on a callback there is no need for recursive mutexes at all. Also I wouldn't write a callback mechanism with dynamic polymorphism in this time and age. Just allow for subscription of callback functions (e.g. std::function<void (ArgsT...)>)

For example : https://onlinegdb.com/avtl6-ZYN (something I cooked up earlier)

I do need to unsubscribe in a callback.
Can you expand on why subscribing a callback function would be preferred to a polymorphic Update() function? In my use case every callback function would have the same signature. It shifts the memory problem from checking the polymorphic object exists to checking that the object owning the callback exists?

@pptaszni Thanks, fixed a couple of typos and added example usage (didn't get smaller unfortunately). Calling m_condition.notify_all(); alone is not enough since the queue remains empty so the predicate on the condition variable is unmet. I agree its hacky, do you have an alternative?

If unsubscribe in callback is a common scenario, then make Update return a value. E.g. true to continue receiving updates and false to unsubscribe.
I understand that you want to preserve current interface, but the code smell comes from changing subscription when processing subscription. recursive_mutex is a consequence, not a cause.

Also: Why not Rx? It's just a tried observer pattern implementation. IMHO reinventing that today is no different than reinventing List.

@Agent_L That is a good suggestion, alongside disallowing Unsubscribe from within Update. I'm not sure I like it more than the weak_ptr change but it does solve the problem with a minor interface change.

The reason you need a recursive mutex is you have to call the callback from within a lock which then can call the unsubscribe method (which would need the lock to update its administration).  The only "workaround" is similar to what boost signals does, allow for a data race and copy the list of subscribers (in a lock) and then start calling the subsribers.

The reason to use std::function instead of runtime polymorphic code is you get more flexibility (use of lambdas etc) and reusability. The infrastructur can be adapted to any function signature returning a void (or as mentioned later a bool, which I think is a nice option).  The client code also becomes more losely coupled since it won't have to use the abstract baseclass (any callback convertible to a std::function will do)

After some look over the PubSub I think that it would be enough to have just 1 std::mutex and lock it for the entire loop iteration in PubSubThread, with some yield or sleep, or cv.wait in the end. Then each other public interface also needs to acquire the lock and you are not allowed to use them inside the callback.

If you want to use PubSub interfaces inside the callback, then in every loop iteration first you need to make modifications to all your queues under lock, prepare the object that needs to be called, then unlock, and then invoke the callback.

I don't think I understand the weak_ptr approach. I thought it's a fix for deleted observers, not for Unsubscribe (which implies the objects continues to live, just without notifications).

You're right, a weak_ptr approach doesn't entirely resolve the problem. If an observer unsubscribes another observer which is then Updated later in the iteration, that would be an error. But that is acceptable if there is no risk that the observer has been destroyed (it also isn't done anywhere).

@pptaszni I think even that isn't enough. If you release the lock to make the callback then there is the possibility that an Observer is unsubscribed and destroyed between releasing the lock and calling the callback. This is what originally prompted the question, as that happened in a test I was writing (before the recursive mutex).
